# What font is this?

Tags: fonts

Can anyone tell me where the script L in the following snippet comes from? It's not `\mathcal{L}`:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`mathrsfs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs) provides `\mathscr` for script mathematical letters, rather than redefining `\mathcal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{L}u$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also consider reading this entry on the TeX FAQ: [Better script fonts for maths](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-scriptfonts).

Comment: Thanks. (I keep forgetting about the TeX FAQ. I should stop doing that.)